# Difference between Locks and .join() method

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say you have two threads, thread1 and thread2. If you call thread1.start() and thread2.start() at the same time and they both print out numbers between 1 and 5, they will both run at the same time and they will randomly print out the numbers in any order, if I am not mistaken. To prevent this, you use the .join() method to make sure that a certain thread gets executed first. If this is what the .join() method does, what is the Lock object used for?

Answer (score 1):

Thread.join is used to wait for another thread to finish. The join method uses the implicit lock on the Thread object and calls wait on it. When the thread being waited for finishes it notifies the waiting thread so it can stop waiting.

Java has different ways to use locks to protect access to data. There is implicit locking that uses a lock built into every Java object (this is where the synchronized keyword comes in), and then there are explicit Lock objects. Both of them protect data from concurrent access, the difference is the explicit Locks are more flexible and powerful, while implicit locking is designed to be easier to use.

With implicit locks, for instance, I can't not release the lock at the end of a synchronized method or block, the JVM makes sure that the lock gets released as the thread leaves. But programming with implicit locks can be limiting. For instance, there aren't separate condition objects so if there are different threads accessing a shared object for different things, notifying only a subset of them is not possible.

With explicit Locks you get separate condition objects and can notify only those threads waiting on a particular condition (producers might wait on one condition while consumers wait on another, see the ArrayBlockingQueue class for an example), and you can implement more involved kinds of patterns, like hand-over-hand locking. But you need to be much more careful, because the extra features introduce complications, and releasing the lock is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Locking typically prevents more than one thread from running a block of code at the same time.  This is because only ONE thread at a time can acquire the lock and run the code within.  If a thread wants the lock but it is already taken, then that thread goes into a wait state until the lock is released.  If you have many threads waiting for the lock to be released, which one gets the lock next is INDETERMINATE (can't be predicted).  This can lead to "thread starvation" where a thread is waiting for the lock, but it just never gets it because other threads always seem to get it instead.  This is a very generic answer because you didn't specify a language.  Some languages may differ slightly in that they might have a determinate method of deciding who gets the lock next.

Comment: The language that I am using is Java, are there any specifics with this language?